# Facebook's "View As..." returns blank profile?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-timeline

I am using the "View As..." tool to see how a certain person sees my profile.

But it turns up empty! No timeline, just a blank page after my cover and profile pics.

This doesn't make sense since we are Facebook friends and my profile privacy rules says all timeline posts are open to all friends.

In addition this person is not in any special list (and needless to say, other people that I tested - view my profile just fine).

Something to consider: this person has blocked writing on their timeline (at least, I can't write on their timeline, and I see only posts written by him).

What is going on?

Answer (score -1):

I do not understand your question. You mention your profile and another person's profile.

I tried doing what you said on my profile and it works decent.

"View As" works only on your profile and it simulates how your profile looks to the general public (If the privacy setting is set to Anyone can view my profile) or you can type in a friends name and see how does your profile look to them. I do not think you can search for a person who has either blocked you or is not on your friends list

Besides these two I do not think there is any other functionality. Atleast not that I know of.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Tintin, I'm not sure wer'e on the same page here. I am using the View As... tool to see how this specific person sees my personal profile, as you said. The thing is... my profle looks empty to him! According to Facebook's tool. http://imgur.com/5Qf9Szt

Comment: Hi Django, Thanks for the clarification. I understand you now. You would be surprised that I found to be in the same situation with a friend of mine(With whom I haven't spoken for a long time on facebook ). When I select that persons name I cannot see anything except my profile and cover pic. 
However, I have not added that person to any list and I can post to that persons timeline.(I just tried that)

Comment: I see. So it got nothing to do with restrictions to posting on the profile. But it's puzzling, that's for sure. Maybe it suggests to some action that that person did toward me/you on facebook... The person I was checking on is also someone I have not spoken to for a long time. In addition, I'm just guessing now, they also changed their name on facebook a while ago.

Comment: Yes! you are right ! facebook keeps changing its privacy settings with time . May be its coz of some settings being set by facebook by default while changing its privacy settings.

Comment: Wait, your friend also changed their name on facebook?

Comment: No , the name has not changed.